# How long should I keep a deprecated function?

Tags: r, deprecated, r-package

For R packages, is there a guideline for how long I should keep around an obsolete function once I deprecate it? What about demoting to defunct? De-thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

I admit that this question is mostly opinion based, but here are some thoughts.

Hadley Wickham ran a [poll on twitter](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/1582776019965992961) asking a very similar question, and the majority of people voted that he should wait 4-5 years  before removing a deprecated function. Granted, it was the shortest available option in the poll, but the next most popular answer was 10+ years.

Now, it of course depends on *how* you are deprecating it. The documentation of the {lifecycle} packages gathers some thoughts around function deprecation and is worth a read. The [{lifecycle} article](https://lifecycle.r-lib.org/articles/communicate.html) suggests first to issue a warning when a function is used in the global environment and testthat functions (i.e. not when other developers use your soft-deprecated function in their packages). Next to issue hard warnings every time and lastly to have the function return an error every time.

Things change a little when you have released very similar functionality under a different function name, which is called 'superseding' a function. I think this fine for any update. My advice would be to using something along the following lines:

```r
# Your function that supercedes the older one
plus <- function(x, y) x + y

# Your deprecated function
add <- function(x, y) {
  warning("`add()` is deprecated. Using `plus()` instead.")
  plus(x, y)
}
```

Another thing you could do is to scour the internet (or GitHub) for a verbatim search `library(your_package)` or `your_package::my_to_be_deprecated_function` to see if and how other people are using it in code that they share (and whether that code is just an one-off analysis script or intended to be re-used by others). If you find someone has a use-case that cannot be easily superseded with another function, you might think about keeping it around for longer or soft-deprecating it instead of hard-deprecating it.

If you find out people barely use your function, your package isn't on a centralised repository (CRAN / Bioconductor) or you haven't advertised your function anywhere, I personally think you're allowed to take more liberties than if you're the developer behind the `base::data.frame()` function.

Comment: Bioconductor has [Deprecation Guidelines](https://contributions.bioconductor.org/deprecation.html), with some points about timing.

Comment: Good point. It is also worth noting that unlike CRAN, Bioconductor has release cycles, which relieves some constraints on backward compatibility (i.e., you don't need to be compatible with previous versions of Bioconductor).